# Interpreting and finetuning the BATCHSIZE parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

So I am playing around with the `BULK INSERT` statement and am beginning to love it. What was talking the `SQL Server Import/Export Wizard` 7 hours is taking only 1-3 hours using `BULK INSERT`. However, what I am observing is that the time to completion is heavily dependent on the `BATCHSIZE` specification.

Following are the times I observed for a 5.7 GB file containing 50 million records:

```
BATCHSIZE = 50000,  Time Taken: 17.30 mins
BATCHSIZE = 10000,  Time Taken: 14:00 mins
BATCHSIZE = 5000 ,  Time Taken: 15:00 mins
```

This only makes me curious: Is it possible to determine a good number for `BATCHSIZE` and if so, what factors does it depend on and can it be approximated without having to run the same query tens of times?

My next run would be a 70 GB file containing 780 million records. Any suggestions would be appreciated? I will report back the results once I finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188267.aspx) and it appears the batch size should be as large as is practical; documentation states in general the larger the batch size the better the performance, but you are not experiencing that at all.  Seems that 10k is a good batch size to start with, but I would look at optimizing the bulk insert from other angles such as putting the database into simple mode or specifying a tablock hint during your import race.

Comment: +1 Thank You! I did not think of either of them. Hopefully, it will show some performance improvement :)